# why readonly attribute doesn't works for h:selectManyCheckbox?

Tags: jsf

if an h:selectManyCheckbox has a attribute readonly="true", the user could not able to check or uncheck the checkbox. but able to click on it, why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As on every other HTML `input` element, the `readonly` attribute only applies on the input element's **value**, not on the checkbox's state. This is indeed pretty unintuitive.

You can use JavaScript to let the `onclick` return `false` when the readonly state is `true`.

```
onclick="return #{!bean.readonly}" readonly="#{bean.readonly}"
```

Please note that this unintuitive behaviour is not related to JSF, but to HTML.